# Make the 'Possible Duplicate:' uneditable by normal users

Tags: feature-request

I noticed a post that had the

> marked as duplicate by:...

But the

```
Possible Duplicate:
.....
```

in the question wasn't there, at first I thought it was a bug, but another user informed me that it was removed in an edit.

That surprised me that a user just can edit out or `Rollback to Revision X`, to an earlier time.

My suggestion: make the: `Possible Duplicate:...` stamp in the answer uneditable. Only by mods or one with a high enough reputation!

- [Photoshop Installation in 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/231512/36315)

**EDIT**:

The user rolled it back again:

- [Photoshop Installation in 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/231512/36315)

I informed the user to stop rolling back, and re-added the duplicate stamp.

Comment: They actually haven't been able to edit the message for some time now, there was just too much overhead to go back and update all the old posts that had been closed before that change.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually in our gift to resolve.

Either "prod a mod" to reopen - close with the dupe link and edit out the old dupe text or alternatively, gather your forces together - say in the general room - to find like minded fellow members to force a reopen and then close

In this case - I've gone ahead and used the mod supervote open and close.